# CakePHP Tree behavior error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

The actual error I'm getting:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'children' at line 1

It drives me nuts and don't even imagine why it is being raised.

In my controller `CategoryController.php` I have:

```
public function index($id = null) {
    $this->set('categories', $this->Category->children($id, true));
```

In model `Category.php`:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable', 'Tree');
```

CakePHP version : 2.4.1

Comment: Activate debug mode and share the SQL queries that Cake does, please. There is an SQL syntax error, as the error message clearly states.

Comment: It's not getting to the point where it generates sql query

Comment: @Mopheus Well it obviously if it’s throwing a MySQL syntax error.

Comment: Did you debug() `$this->Category`, if its the actual (valid) model? If it falls back to AppModel due to a configuration error this would explain the error you are seeing.

Comment: @mark yes, it falls back to AppModel. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, this can only happen when your model configuration is wrong, and your model falls back to the AppModel.

You should debug `$this->Category`.
Inside a plugin for example, you need to define the relationship including the plugin name:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'PluginName.Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
    )
);
```

Pro-tip: To avoid this happening to me by accident, I have the following snippet included for development setup: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/MyModel.php#L45